# why did not save form data in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am using Auth: command register form in My laravel application. and I have add new nic input box to register.blade.php file as this,
register.blade.php

```
 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('nic') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="nic" class="col-md-4 control-label">NIC</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nic" type="text" class="form-control" name="nic">

                                @if ($errors->has('nic'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nic') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and MY AuthController is like this,

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'nic' => 'required|min:10',
            ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'nic' => $data['nic'],
        ]);
    }
```

and I have new column as **nic** in Users table as well. but when I click register button other data values saving well in users table but nic column not saving nic values. how can solve this problem?

Comment: no any sujjection here

Comment: Is `nic` set to `fillable` in your user class?

Comment: yes now it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your User model if nic is added in `$fillable` array because you do a [mass assignement](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Backpack\Base\app\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification as ResetPasswordNotification;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'nic'];

}
```